# Macbook stuck on the loading screen

Tags: boot, memory, macbook

My Macbook stuck on the grey screen with the apple logo and the spinning wheel. I changed RAM memory (after crash) recently, but it worked fine for some time.

I've already tried and it didn't help:

- Reseted the PRAM (command, alt, r, p) - restared fine but no
     change.
- Started the machine in single user mode by holding down
     "s" on startup. (not working)
- Removed any third party RAM and
     unplug anything from the machine that doesn't need to be plugged
     (printer, external HDD etc). (no change)
- Useed install disc and
     run disc utility.  S.M.A.R.T was marked as checked and no errors or
     warning appeared, but "check" or "repair" buttons were not active
     (was not possible to click on them) - don't know if it's ok, for
     main hardrive.

Please, if anyone has any advice or tip I would greatly appreciate it. What could be the reason of the problem?

Kind regard